# Is there a way to disable update notifications in Mojave?

Tags: software-update, notifications, mojave

Short of killing all notifications, is there a way to stop "Updates Available" notifications from showing up, for app and system updates?

- I already have "Automatically keep my Mac up to date" unchecked in Sys Prefs > Software Update
- Everything in "Advanced..." there is unchecked
- App Store > Prefs > Automatic Updates is unchecked

To head off any frame challenges, yes, I do perform regular manual updates, but when it doesn't interrupt my work. No, I will not tolerate automatic updates, and it doesn't matter why.  Maybe I need a stable setup for development, video rendering, or I just don't like to be bothered with notifications about something that may require a restart, shutdown of critical apps, or any interruption to my work flow.

Comment: I don't think so. If they really annoy you then kill all the notifications

Comment: Given all the research I've done, that may be the only viable option, but I do use notifications for some things, so I'd have to weigh the annoyance vs. missing an important communication or something.

Comment: I see, sorry if i am wrong with this but can't you just disable setting notifications

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an option for settings, sys prefs, or app store in notifications.

Comment: as you know it is the App Store sending you updates for the OSX and all apps downloaded from there.

Comment: System updates now have their own place to live in sys prefs in Mojave. Still, I haven't found a way to stop notification coming from either Software Update or the App Store.

Comment: Another reference covering the steps in the OP: 
 https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/macos-mojave-disable-all-automatic-updates/  These steps do not seem to disable App Store notifications in Mojave.

Comment: Mojave is nagging me every day about updating, but I would rather just focus on work and update in a week. There's no option to say "Remind me in a week." I hoped to stop the prompts by disabling automatic updates and downloads. Some update files are already downloaded though. Can I delete the 2.8GB of files and download them again later? Nope. Not even with `sudo`. "Operation not permitted". Not only does Apple nag me daily but they force me to keep files I don't want. It's like I don't own my computer and am just leasing it from Apple so they will bother me when it's convenient for them.

Comment: This would not be nearly as aggravating if they would just let me dismiss it like any other notification, but they force the appstore to open.  Reminds me of the old days of bloatware being installed on windows computer.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report for this issue (and I do believe it should be categorized as a bug not a 'suggestion') using Apple's Feedback Assistant and I encourage everyone here to do the same. If you'd like to include in your feedback a recommendation for how Apple could fix this issue, I think suggesting that they include App Store in the Notifications System Preference would be best.

Comment: @GuyGizmo Great idea.  Here is a link to that https://feedbackassistant.apple.com and, and here is a template to use for your description https://gist.github.com/jordanglassman/a4915130d84f3e3d4638b5212d6edfa9

Answer (score 6):

If you want to disable updates for specific apps, you can use `softwareupdate --ignore`.

Do all the following in Terminal

Start with

```
softwareupdate -l
```

to list all available updates,

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist
```

to find the Identifier of the app you want to ignore, and then

```
softwareupdate --ignore 'Identifier'
```

to ignore the update. Should disappear from Software Updates in System Preferences immediately.

Comment: When I run the list command it only shows a Mojave update, not any app updates. Same with the identifier plist, it doesn't show any apps, just "macOS 10.14.6 Update". Is this supposed to show app updates as well? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

### No

After hours on the phone with Apple's techs, the answer is simply that there currently isn't a way to silence notifications. They have various workarounds, like uninstalling any apps that might have updates or silencing all notifications, but all of them have undesirable side effects, unfortunately.

Comment: AppleCare support will never tell you about solutions that *aren't officially supported*. If there is a way to do it by digging around in your system's settings through Terminal and tinkering with things, don't expect to find out from them. (Because even though that solution may be great for *you*, your less savvy grandma will try the same thing, get some crucial step wrong, and render her Mac unusable...then blame Apple) It's sad, but just the way it is.

Comment: True enough, but I suppose I should add that this includes the outside research I have been doing, as well as the other suggested solutions that this question has generated.

Answer (score 2):

I just found this workaround:

- Backup and remove `/Library/Bundles/OSXNotification.bundle`
- run `softwareupdate --ignore macOSInstallerNotification_GM` in a terminal

[http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/26/stop-upgrade-macos-mojave-notifications/]

Comment: I'm already in Mojave, that is I'm running 10.14.1. Does this solution work for other updates as well (minor OS security updates, App Store updates)?

Comment: This is only applies to the specific case of upgrading the OS itself.  The OP is referring to notifications that cannot be disabled _after_ upgrading to Mojave.

Comment: @JWBH Sorry, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm pretty sure turning Do Not Disturb for the Notification Center would do the trick?
2. After doing a `sudo defaults read com.apple.SoftwareUpdate`, and changing the values of `AutomaticCheckEnabled` and/or `CriticalUpdateInstall` as necessary, you could always `sudo defaults write com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL -string 'https://127.0.0.1'`. You'd never get an update notification again. Nor, of course, an update, but...

Answer (score 0):

No solution would permit user-initiated updates yet suppress all automatic updates and notifications.

Still, two more partial workarounds could be considered to get closer to the desired state:

1. Push notifications promoting major OS upgrades can be suppressed with a future-dated `MajorOSUserNotificationDate` key (via [Jeff Johnson](https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/2024/2/2.html), [Michael Tsai](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2024/02/09/how-to-stop-macos-upgrade-notifications/)):

   `defaults write com.apple.SoftwareUpdate MajorOSUserNotificationDate -date "2038-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"`
2. MDM policy keys allowing deferral of up to 90 days for application updates, non-OS upgrades, minor OS upgrades, and major OS upgrades for personal Macs (i.e., devices not subject to Apple’s Device Enrollment Program): [guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/test-and-defer-software-updates-depd30715cbb/web), [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/restrictions).

   For example, setting `forceDelayedMajorSoftwareUpdates` to `true` and `enforcedSoftwareUpdateMajorOSDeferredInstallDelay` to `90` would suppress major OS update availability for 90 days.